# Parsing json response using Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm having this json resonse in postman...

```
    {
        "errorcode": "0",
        "errorstr": "Success",
        "result": {
        "top": [
          "id": 826133
          "deal_detail": "<p><strong>Main link <a href=\"https://links.de.com?ref=forums&url=https://pa.com/deal-on--clpid-7960\" target=\"\" rel=\…</p>
         ],

       “popular”: [
         "id": 826133
         "deal_detail": "<p><strong>Main link <a href=\"https://links.de.com?ref=forums&url=https://pa.com/deal-on--clpid-7960\" target=\"\" rel=\…</p>
         ],

"categories": {
            "1": "Fashion & Apparels",
            "2": "Mobiles & Mobile Accessories",
            "3": "Computers, laptops & Accessories",
            "4": "Electronics",
        },
        "stores": {
            "1": "Amazon",
            "75": "Dominos",

        }
    }
```

I was trying to proceed with the parsing of this json response like so...

`if let orderData = result["result"] as? [[String:Any]] {...` But since result is not an array, I don't think this is the right approach.

What could be the right approach...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result can be array and dictionary, both are good approach. But in your case, it is dictionary not any array, so treat it like accordingly and do as below

```
let orderData = result["result"] as? [String:Any] // Now in orderData you have result
```

Now parse further data according to it.

Still any issue or unclear then ask.

Comment: Yes..I'm trying...Taking time to load...:)

Comment: I tried something like so...`if result["errorstr"] as! String == "Success" {
if let orderData = result["result"] as? [String:Any] {
for order in orderData {
print(order)
}}}` and printing `order` gives me each key and their values. But in order to get each values from the key `top` when I do like so `guard let top = order["top"] as? [String: Any]` it throws and error..

Comment: @v.bw Check your json again.. If structure enclosing with `[...]` then it is array and if it is enclosing like this `{...}` then it is dict. Now see carefully your json structure -> `"top": [...] // It is array` and `"stores": {...} //It is dict`. We identify dict and array with these braces. For top you have use `[[String : Any]] // Array of dict`.

Comment: ok @dahiya_boy. So is`"top": [...]` is an array of dictionary..?

Comment: @v.bw Can you give your api show that i can check here. bcz i have doubt on the response that you added in your question. It has many errors so its hard to me to say anything by the way you check your json response from here -> https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168270/discussion-between-v-bw-and-dahiya-boy).

Answer (score 1):

Use [**AlamofireObjectMapper**](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper). It would make your work very easy.
1. 1. Create your model class based on the JSON response you are getting. The above link has examples. It should be same as the JSON representation.
2. Parse JSON as follow :

```
Alamofire.request(URL).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<YourModel>) in

let modelResponse = response.result.value   
// your code 
}
```

Comment: I wanted to know how to create model mappable class of `objectmapper`??  **Either** i have to create manually by checking the response (I don't think it is suitable) **or** there is any online or offline software in which I pass my json structure and it creates the mappable file for me. (I searched alot but I never get any thing like this). Pls let me know how to create mappable file?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to go for a famous library that is used for response parsing named SwiftyJSON.This will reduce your effort as well as time.